# Best practice for changing opensource used in commercial application?

Tags: git, version-control, open-source

probably basic conduct but still vague for me:

We're developing a **commercial** application using an open source component (apache hive), and we're using the latest 'stable' version (0.7.1), not the bleeding edge trunk.

We need to make some changes to the component, as there are some bugs we need fixed. We want to contribute them, **but we can't be dependent on the opensource commiters**. So we want to make changes in a local copy, compile the jar and use it in our app.

How should we deal with our local changes? do we maintain a copy of the opensource project in our own svn? do we copy it from the "branches" or from the "tags" of the hive svn? how do we then merge our changes back to the opensource svn - as their branch might be different from ours by the time we get there, and if we create a patch from our svn it might not fit their svn...

Thanks, ido

edit: what do you guys say about using git? could the answer to our process challenge be techy? it seems that this particular opensource also exposes a git repository, will it help us to create a local copy of it? if so, do we create it from the tag/branch/trunk? remember that we need to use and do our patches **on a stable version** but contribute to the **bleeding edge trunk**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about development methodologies and software licensing are better suited to Programmers.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a patch for one version it may or may not improve/be applicable to another version. The bug may already be fixed or the functionality addressed already removed. At the very least some effort will be needed to integrate the changes.

That said I think your best bet is to go with cloning their git repo on an intranet server. Then you can create a branch from the stable tag (say `our_stable_branch`). Your devs will be able to clone this intranet repo and push whatever changes they make into `our_stable_branch`. Then when you want to you can merge the changes into master and push them to the main apache hive repo.

Comment: sounds good. just to clear it up: you're suggesting that we clone the entire git repo = trunk + branches, then choose the branch we like, push changes into it, then push to our local trunk, then push to the main hive repo trunk. right?

Comment: Something like that. Just read up on git first. Some things are a bit different than SVN. For example you clone the whole repo by default. Also any repo may become an upstream repo for some other repo, branches behave a bit different, etc.